# Natural language examples for failure of double negation elimination

Tags: logic, philosophy, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I am trying to explain why double negation *elimination* $\neg \neg \phi \vdash \phi$  is invalid in intuitionistic logic, but *introduction* $\phi \vdash \neg \neg \phi$ is valid.

The latter is easy: if I can prove $\phi$, then I can prove that '$\phi$ is contradictory' is contradictory. I might explain this by saying that "if I can see that your coat is blue, then I can immediately construct a contradiction from (your coat is not blue)".

For elimination, one can see how having a proof that `$\phi$ is contradictory' is contradictory doesn't furnish you with a proof of $\phi$ itself, but in my experience people don't find examples like "'(your coat is not blue) is contradictory' does not give a proof that your coat is blue" very convincing.

What I would like is a similar simple natural language example that makes it clear that elimination is not straightforwardly valid.

Comment: It would be helpful to give a bit more context: are you preparing a presentation or just trying to explain things to yourself? In any case, If you haven't heard of the [BHK interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov_interpretation), then that would be a good thing for you to investigate.

Comment: Just trying to get a grip on it in a way that I could explain it to a layman. I understand the BHK interpretation; what I'm looking for is an example of a situation outside of maths and computer science where one could illustrated that elimination is not necessarily a valid means of argument.

Comment: The rejection of double elimination as an axiom doesn't mean it is invalid or false.  Just that it isn't given to you for free, you have to assume it explicitly.  It may be more illuminating to ask "how does this change the way logic is organized" more than "is there ever a case when it would be invalid".  The expressiveness of the positive partial fragment of propositional logic makes separating double elimination from the rest of the definitions very clean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even in intuitionistic logic, double negation elimination holds for statements that have to be true or false, in this sense: there is an intuitionistic proof that
$$
(\phi \lor \lnot \phi) \to (\lnot \lnot \phi \to \phi).
$$
The proof is as follows, by cases: First, if $\phi$, then $\lnot \lnot \phi \to \phi$ trivially. Second, if $\lnot \phi$, then $\lnot \lnot \phi$ implies $\bot$, and $\bot$ implies $\phi$. So overall we would conclude $\lnot \lnot \phi \to \phi$ in each case.

This has an informal consequence for natural language examples: it is necessary to avoid statements for which the audience already believes $\phi \lor \lnot\phi$.

One possibility is to use a *modal* interpretation of intuitionistic logic instead. So asserting $\phi$ means that $\phi$ is certain, and asserting $\lnot \phi$ means that $\phi$ is impossible.

In this interpretation, we see that $\phi \to \lnot \lnot \phi$ holds because, if $\phi$ is certain, then it is impossible for $\phi$ to be impossible.

But $\lnot \lnot \phi \to \phi$ does not hold in this interpretation because, just because it is impossible for $\phi$ to be impossible, this does not mean that $\phi$ must be certain. Perhaps $\phi$ is only a possibility, neither certain nor impossible.

So, in natural language, if I say: "There is no chance that it is impossible that it will rain tomorrow", this does not imply "It is certain that it will rain tomorrow".

Similarly, DanielV gave a nice example which could be restated as follows. If I say, "It is impossible to say that it is impossible for the defendant to be innocent", this does not allow the jury to conclude that the defendant is innocent.

This relationship between modal logic and intuitionistic logic shows up formally: both of these logics have natural [Kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics#Semantics_of_intuitionistic_logic), and Kripke semantics are one way to verify formally that intuitionistic logic does not prove double negation elimination.

Comment: This also helps to explain how intuitionistic logic doesn't prove $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$. In the modal interpretation I mentioned, that formula says that $\phi$ is certain or $\phi$ is impossible. So, for $\phi=$ "it will rain tomorrow", this interpretation won't let us assert $\phi \lor \lnot \phi$.

Answer (score 2):

First, I like to formulate *classical* truth as irrefutability, i.e. some proposition being classically true means that "you cannot refute it".  This is essentially the double negation embedding of classical logic into intuitionistic logic.

For constructive logic, the main thing to lean on is constructions or explicit evidence.  Changing your wording to something like "can demonstrate" or "have evidence for" helps make what's going on clearer.  I'm assuming you want a non-technical "day-to-day" example.  It's much easier to make unambiguous technical examples.  A non-technical example is going to be less crisp, neveretheless here's one:

> Let's say I brought lunch and placed it in the company refrigerator. 
>   Come lunch time I find it missing.  No one can refute that someone
>   took my lunch, but I have no evidence that some particular person took
>   my lunch.  Specifically, I don't know who it was nor do I have
>   evidence that that particular person took my lunch.

This can be tightened by providing a specific definition for "evidence", for example, "video evidence".  Maybe I filmed myself placing my lunch in the refrigerator, and, of course, I can film that the refrigerator is now empty, but I have no *video* evidence of someone taking my lunch.  Note how constructively proving $\exists x.\varphi(x)$ requires actually explicitly providing the relevant "$x$", i.e. I can't constructively know $\exists x.\varphi(x)$ and not know a specific $t$ such that $\varphi(t)$ is true.

Again, differentiating between something "being true" versus "having evidence for" something is a key part of understanding constructivism.

Answer (score 2):

Not everyone agrees on conceptualizations of constructive logic, but one way of looking at it is that constructive logic doesn't address true/false, it only addresses provable/not provable.  So $\lnot P$ doesn't mean that $P$ is false in material terms, it means that it is not provable in an algorithmic sense.

Prosecutor : "The defense says I can't prove the defendant is guilty.  But they can't prove that."
Defense : "This is true."
Prosecutor : "Therefore he is guilty."
Jury: "Agree."

This is one conceptualization of what $\lnot \lnot P \implies P$ means in constructive logic, and why it isn't taken as an axiom.

Comment: $\lnot P$ would even mean $P$ is strongly disprovable, not just that it's not provable. This answer has a good example in natural language.